# Comparing dates with IF statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following two tables `education` and `jobs` each with timestamp field. In a sequel statement, I want to select and determine which of the two timestamps held on both tables is the most current.

I have attempted below with no joy;

```
  SELECT e.StartDate, j.LastTimeModified, 
   IF(e.StartDate > j.LastTimeModified)
    THEN e.StartDate
   ELSEIF (j.LastTimeModified > e.StartDate)
    THEN j.LastTimeModified
  AS lastmodified FROM education e, jobs j;
```

Any pointers -:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use another IF construction, e.g. -

```
SELECT IF(a > b, column1, column2) FROM table
```

For more complex solutions use CASE WHEN function, e.g. -

```
SELECT CASE WHEN a > b THEN column1 WHEN a < b THEN column2 ELSE column3 END FROM table;
```

Documentation: [Control Flow Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html).